# Pick file to restore database android

Tags: android, backup

I have an app with a database in it. I have a method to backup the database like this:

```
// Method To Backup Database//
public void OnClick_Backup(View v) {

    // Vibrates For 50 Mill//
    vibe.vibrate(50);

    // Get Calendar Instance//
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Get Date//
    SimpleDateFormat mFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");

    // Create App Folder//
    File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/C.S. Tracker Backups");
    if(!sd.exists()){
        sd.mkdirs();
    }
        try {
            File sd2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            // Backup File//
            if (sd2.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//jordanzimmittidevelopers.com.communityservicelogger//databases//community_service_Database";
                String backupDBPath = "/C.S. Tracker Backups/" + mFormatter.format(c.getTime());
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd2, backupDBPath);

                // Replace File If It has Same Name//
                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup is successful to SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
```

And another method to restore the database like this:

```
// Method To Restore Database//
public void OnClick_Restore(View v) {

    // Vibrates For 50 Mill//
    vibe.vibrate(50);

    // Get Calendar Instance//
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Get Date//
    SimpleDateFormat mFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");

    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//jordanzimmittidevelopers.com.communityservicelogger//databases//community_service_Database";
            String backupDBPath = "/C.S. Tracker Backups/" + mFormatter.format(c.getTime());
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Restored successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

The problem is I have it so when the user hits backup it saves a file on there phone with the date of the backup. So if there are multiple backups I want them to be able to click which backup they want to restore in like a popup box or something. Thanks

edit: to claify how do I do this= So if there are multiple backups I want them to be able to click which backup they want to restore in like a popup box or something.

Comment: Yes. That is a good idea. Or use a file picker. What is the problem?

Comment: I have no idea how to get the user to be able to click on the backup they want. It only defaults to the most recent one

Comment: If you backup today and want to restore tomorrow then that backup cannot be found with the code you have now. So what do you mean with that it defaults to the most recent one?

Comment: If they backup multiple times. Like once every day for 3 days. It will only restore the one one the third day. I want them to be able to pick the first second or third day

Comment: One of the possibilities is to use a file picker. Or list all files from your directory in an String array and use an AlertDialog.Builder to let the user choose from them.

Comment: I got close with using that but once I click on the file I dont know how to get it to run the code I have

Comment: Simply remove all view garbage from your restore function and give it a parameter String backupDBPath. `String backupDBPath = full path from filepicker; restore (backupDBPath);`

Comment: can you please show an example using my code

Comment: `It will only restore the one one the third day`. No. Not if it is already the fourth day.

Comment: Actually no even if it is the forth day it will sill restore the third day I already tested this and it worked

Comment: That is impossible. Because when the last backup has 12-03-15 in its filename and you request the next day the 13-03-15 it will not be found.

Comment: thats because its not looking for the name its looking for the file in the folder directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String backupDBPath = here get full path from filepicker; 

 restore (backupDBPath);
```

And this is your function:

```
 public boolean restore(String backupDBPath) {

    File backupDB  = new File( backupDBPath);
    if (!backupDB.exists())
{
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
    , "file not found:\n"+backupDB.getAbsolutePath()
    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return false;
}

   File currentDB = getDatabasePath("community_service_Database");
   if (!currentDB.exists())
{
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
    , "file not found:\n"+currentDB.getAbsolutePath()
    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return false;
}

   try {

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Restored successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;

  } catch (Exception e) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception:\n"+e.getMessage()(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return false;
}
```

}